# New servers aren't displayed in docker weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: oracle, docker, weblogic

I'm trying to create new servers linked to the adminServer in weblogic. So I followed this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/DOCKR/configuration.htm).

I managed to create successful the wlsadmin (container name) server and then I try to create other to Servers:

```
docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin -p 7002:7001 -p 7003:7002 1221-domain createServer.sh
docker run -d --link wlsadmin:wlsadmin -p 7004:7001 1221-domain createServer.sh
```

they get created successfuly, but in the admin-console under the `Environment/Servers` they aren't displayed at all, but in the `Environment\Machines` two new `Machines` are created.

`Docker network inspect bridge` shows me that the containers are in the same network and `docker ps` shows me that the containers are running (also I can get inside them).

The `docker logs` doesn't show any error.

This means I cannot install any `.war-s`

Any idea what is wrong with the setup?

---

Weblogic Version: 12.2.1
Docker Version: 17.03.1-ce

Comment: Try to add option --net:  `docker run --net=host...`

Comment: @mulg0r doesn't help, again it adds the server to `machines`, but isn't visible in the `servers`

Comment: Maybe are you missing any ENV?

Comment: I don't think so, because this setup I have it done 3 months ago and now I just modified something in a file that's added by the image build and I rebuild the image (1221-domain). So nothing else is changed. And before has worked, now doesn't and the change in the file is just app specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution: to add the servers manually (before the servers were added automatically).

Steps:

1. go to `Environment\Machines`
2. select a machine and go to server tab
3. add new server (check ip with docker inspect container)
4. click on server and add it to the `Docker cluster`
5. go on `Environment\Servers` and click on `Control` tab
6. start the new server